# Why I cannot take the Address of & a function in golang but can for a function value

Tags: go

Say I declare a func in golang:

```
    func myFunc() {     
    }
```

It is an error to declare a function pointer taking the address of the function

```
fp := &myFunc
```

"invalid operation: cannot take address of myFunc (value of type func())"

However, I can assign it to a function value and take the address

```
functionValue := myFunc
fp := &function
```

Is "functionValue" any different from using the function name "myFunc"?
Aren't they both of the same type? (func())

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`myFunc` is a function. `functionValue` is a function variable, which is a variable pointing to a function, and a closure. For instance:

```
var x int
functionValue:=func() int {return x}
```

Above, `functionValue` is a function variable with the closure containing a reference to `x`.

A named function like `myFunc` does not have a closure associated with it. A function variable like `functionValue` has a closure. When you assign it to `myFunc` that closure is empty. When you assign it like above, it is non-empty. Because of this, the mechanics of calling a function are different from calling a function variable.

The address of a function variable is just that, the address of that variable.

Comment: so even though they both have the same type (func() ), & operator can only be applied to a function variable and not to a function itself?

Comment: One of them is a variable, so you can take the address of it.

Comment: @zuselegacy, look at it this way: Go only allows addressing things you can modify. Add to that that contrary to C, go does not have "constant variables": a variable is, as its name suggests, something which can be _varied_ through assignment. Now the thing is, you cannot mutate a function at runtime, and that's why you cannot take its address. But if you declare a variable of a matching type, you can assign any named or anonymous function to it—if its signature matches the type of that variable. And now you're free to take the address of that variable since you can mutate its contents.

Comment: @BurakSerdar, I'm afraid you got terminology not quite right, so it might be confusing. A closure in Go is a specific case of a _function literal_ which happens to refer to one or more variables in its outer lexical scope (and so it "closes over" them). The fact you assign anything "callable" to a variable of a matching type does not make neither the variable nor the assigned value a closure, so I would avoid using this term altogether in your answer.

Comment: @zuselegacy, quite the same "weirdness" you might come across as well is the impossibility to take the address of a `map` entry—even though it might be counterintuitive at first glance. The reason is pretty much the same: `map` entries are not variables in Go, and so you cannot take their addresses. The same logic applies to return _values_ of functions: you cannot apply the `&` operator to the result of a function call returning a single value; the reason is the same: it's a value, not a variable, and you can only take addresses of variables.

Comment: @kostix thanks for the explanation! Not allowing & on things that cannot change value make sense. For the same reason, you cannot reassign the function name to some other function which would be absurd
This article https://go101.org/article/function.html describes function names as "immutable function values"

Comment: @kostix, all function variables have closures. If you assign a function variable to a declared function, closure is empty.

Comment: @kostix, that is one of the reasons why you cannot compare two function variables. Even if they point to the same function, their closures may be different.

Comment: I would say it is most akin to a constant. Function values are constant: they are defined at compile time. You cannot take the address of ` const` the same reason you can't take the address of `http.ListenAndServe`. If you assign a variable to hold either one, you can take the address of that variable, because the variable exists in working memory, not just in the compiled executable code.